# Powershell - How to Validate a Form after 'OK' button is clicked instead of using "Validating" event?

Tags: forms, powershell, validation

I've added a function to check for a null textbox using the _Validating event.  I know that the form has a function called ValidateChildren() that check all the controls if they have been validated and will return either true or false.

Does Powershell have any way that I can check an individual control if it has been validated?

Reason I ask is because I'd rather show an ErrorProvider icon on the specific control(s) that are null after an "OK" button is clicked and not after the _validating event is fired.

Comment: I guess I'm not getting what you are trying to do.  My first time experimenting with Validating and successfully converted [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to PowerShell.  Textbox flashes red `!` when leaving control and content does not match an [int]. The code looks like it would be easy to place in the `OK` button - are you have a problem getting it to work in the `OK` button's click event?

Answer (score 0):

Not clear on what you are trying to accomplish that the following example fails at, so please explain.

This example is based on [the C# example found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Clicking the OK button does not close the form, but instead it validates the text box and causes the `!` messaged to appear to the right of the text box when it's content is not an int (same as the original C# code.).

The `Validating` event based on the original C# code can be uncommented, and re-enabled, by changing the line `<## >` to `<##>`.

One important note, this is the first time I've worked with validating and instructions provided with the original C# code from Microsoft says "Add an ErrorProvider component to the form", my interpretation of what this instruction means is expressed in line #4 of the code. It appears to do the job, but if this is correct, I honestly wish the author had stated something like: "create an new instance of ErrorProvider named "errorProvider1."

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
using namespace System.ComponentModel
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$errorProvider1 = [ErrorProvider]::new()
$Edge_XGap = 12
$Edge_YGap = 12
$Ctrl_XGap = 6
$Ctrl_YGap = 6
$Error_XGap = 6
$Button_Height = 23
$Button_Width = 60
$TestForm = [Form]@{
    MaximizeBox = $true
    MinimizeBox = $false
    MinimumSize = '200, 100'
    Name = 'Test Form'
    Size = '325, 125'
    StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
    Text = 'Validation Testing'
    TopMost = $true
}
$InfoTextBox = [TextBox]@{
    Anchor =  'Top, Left, Bottom, Right'
    Location = '12, 12'
    Multiline = $true
    Name = 'InfoTextBox'
    Size = "$($TestForm.ClientSize.Width-($Edge_XGap*2 + $Error_XGap)), $($TestForm.ClientSize.Height-($Edge_XGap*2 + $Ctrl_YGap + $Button_Height))"
    TabIndex = 1
}
$OK_Button = [Button]@{
    Anchor = 'Bottom, Right'
    #DialogResult = [DialogResult]::OK
    Location = "$($TestForm.ClientSize.Width - ($Button_Width + $Edge_XGap)), $($TestForm.ClientSize.Height - ($Button_Height + $Edge_YGap))"
    Name = 'OK_Button'
    Size = "$($Button_Width), $($Button_Height)"
    TabIndex = 2
    Text = 'OK'
    UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
}
$TestForm.Controls.Add($InfoTextBox)
$TestForm.Controls.Add($OK_Button)
$OK_Button.Add_Click({
    try {
        [int]$x = [Int32]::Parse($InfoTextBox.Text)
        $errorProvider1.SetError($InfoTextBox, "")
    }
    catch {
        $errorProvider1.SetError($InfoTextBox, "Not an integer value.")
    }
})
$TestForm.Add_Resize({
    $this.Text = "$($this.Size.ToString())"
})
<## >
$InfoTextBox.Add_Validating({
    param([object]$sender, [CancelEventArgs]$e)
    try {
        [int]$x = [Int32]::Parse($InfoTextBox.Text)
        $errorProvider1.SetError($InfoTextBox, "")
    }
    catch {
        $errorProvider1.SetError($InfoTextBox, "Not an integer value.")
    }
})
#>
$null = $TestForm.ShowDialog()
```